# Returning a vector of references from a Class

Tags: c++, vector, reference

I have a function called FunctionCombiner (of base type ValuationFunction) which contains other valuationFunctions like so:

```
class FunctionCombiner : public valuationFunction
{
public:
    FunctionCombiner(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<valuationFunction>>& Inner_);
    void ValueInstrument();
    std::vector<std::string> GetuniqueIdentifier() const;
    void RiskFactorAdd(double increment, RiskFactor simulatedRiskFactor);
    void RiskFactorMultiply(double factor, RiskFactor simulatedRiskFactor);
    virtual valuationFunction* clone() const;
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<valuationFunction>> Inner;
};
```

What I need to do is create a function that returns references to these "inner" functions but I'm unsure how to go about it, everything I've tried seems to fail syntactically. If I was returning just a refence (not inside a vector) I would go about it like this:

```
valuationFunction& FunctionCombiner ::GetInner()
{
    return *this;
}
```

I've tried returning something like `std::vector< valuationFunction&>` but the compiler doesn't seem to like that very much. What is the correct way to go about this?

The end goal is to collect all these references to the inner functions (from several FunctionCombiners or different valuationFunctions) in order to compare them and sort out duplicates later on.

EDIT: From the answer I've now implemented the function that returns the inner reference like follows:
My functions look like this now for the "inner" classes:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<valuationFunction>> StockPriceFunction::GetInnerReference()
    {
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<valuationFunction>> innerVector(1);
        innerVector.push_back(std::ref(*this));
        return innerVector;
    }
```

And like this for the combiner:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<valuationFunction>> FunctionCombiner::GetInnerReference()
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<valuationFunction>> innerVector(Inner.size());
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < Inner.size(); ++i) {
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<valuationFunction>> innerInnerVector = Inner[i]->GetInnerReference();
        innerVector.insert(innerVector.end(), innerInnerVector.begin(), innerInnerVector.end());
    }
    return innerVector;
}
```

But it's not compiling and giving me strange errors, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You'll have to use `std::reference_wrapper`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Comment: You cannot store references in a vector. The closest you can get is storing `std::reference_wrapper`s or pointers (raw or smart pointers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store references in a `std::vector` you'll have to use an [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

int main( )
{
    std::vector<int> ints{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> references;

    for( auto& i : ints )
        references.push_back( i );

    auto& ref{ references[ 1 ].get( ) };
    ref += 20;

    // Prints 22.
    std::cout << ints[ 1 ] << '\n';
}
```

Here is another example which more closely resembles what you're trying to do (I also included what headers you need).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct ValuationFunction 
{ 
    ValuationFunction( int prop ) 
        : property{ prop } { }
    int property; 
};


// Converts the vector of pointers to a vector 
// of references.
static std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<ValuationFunction>> 
    ToReference( const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ValuationFunction>>& pointers )
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<ValuationFunction>> references;
    references.reserve( pointers.size( ) );

    for ( auto& pointer : pointers )
        references.emplace_back( *pointer );

    return references;
}

int main( )
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ValuationFunction>> pointers
    {
        std::make_shared<ValuationFunction>( 1 ),
        std::make_shared<ValuationFunction>( 2 ),
        std::make_shared<ValuationFunction>( 3 ),
        std::make_shared<ValuationFunction>( 4 )
    };

    auto references{ ToReference( pointers ) };

    // Use 'std::reference_wrapper.get( )' to get
    // access to the contained reference.
    for ( auto& ref : references )    
        std::cout << "Before: " << ref.get( ).property << '\n';

    // Change the property value of each 'ValuationFunction'
    // in the original list.
    for ( auto& pointer : pointers )
        pointer->property += 10;

    // Re-print the property value of each reference and see
    // how they have all increased by 10.
    for ( auto& ref : references )    
        std::cout << "After: " << ref.get( ).property << '\n';    
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you I tried implementing this but it's still not compiling and giving me a million errors, can you look at my Edit and see if I have understood it correctly or am doing something wrong?

Comment: @Oscar OK i'll do an example that's closer to what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Oscar part of your problem was you're trying to default construct the `std::reference_wrapper` via the constructor of `vector`. You cannot default construct a `std::reference_wrapper` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper

Comment: @Oscar I also removed the `std::ref` from the first example as the `helper` function was not needed in that case as I could just use the `std::reference_wrapper` constructor.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, the culprit was that it wasn't letting me default construct the reference_wrapper via the constructor of vector (why on earth I wouldn't be allowed to do that (or why the compiler can't let me know in a more practical manner arghh) is another separate question). Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help. I am going to look over your answer a few more times and hopefully I'll understand a bit better how this all fits together